# Install Ubuntu equivalent libraries in Macos e.g libssl-dev

Tags: macos, ubuntu, unix, homebrew, apt-get

I would like to install ubuntu libraries listed below in macos. Please does anyone know what the equivalent commands in macos terminal are? I have searched homebrew already and they don't exist there.

```
apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev libnet-ssleay-perl libcrypt-ssleay-perl libidn11-dev
```

Any pointers in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- There’s no equivalent to `build-essential` on macOS because those basic tools are already installed.
- [`libssl-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libssl-dev) is OpenSSL: `brew install openssl`
- `libnet-ssleay-perl` and `libcrypt-ssleay-perl` are just Perl modules [`Net::SSLeay`](http://search.cpan.org/~mikem/Net-SSLeay-1.81/lib/Net/SSLeay.pod) and [`Crypt::SSLeay`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-SSLeay/SSLeay.pm). You should be able to install them with `cpan`.
- `libidn11-dev` can be installed with `brew install libidn`. The Debian package installs version 1.29 while Homebrew installs 1.33.

---

For a more generic approach, here is what you can try to "convert" a Debian package name into a Homebrew one:

1. Strip any `-dev` suffix and `brew search` the resulting name; e.g. `libidn11-dev` -> `brew search libidn11`.
2. Try without any version suffix: `brew search libidn`. If you find a match, run `brew info <formula>` to check its version. Note Homebrew sometimes has fixed-version packages, like `openssl@1.1` for `openssl` version 1.1.
3. Search the package on [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org) to see what it installs. For example, [`libssl-dev`’s description](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libssl-dev) says:

   > This package is part of the OpenSSL project's implementation of the SSL and TLS cryptographic protocols for secure communication over the Internet.

   We can then `brew search openssl` to see there’s a package that matches this exactly.

Comment: Thank you I have installed Net::SSLeay but Crypt::SSLeay seems to be failing even with the sudo command. `No 'Makefile' created  NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.0/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK` libidn is not the same version it seems.

Comment: [`libidn11-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libidn11-dev) installs the 1.29 version while Homebrew have a more up-to-date version: 1.33.  Regarding `Crypt::SSLeay` [it seems](http://mail.pm.org/pipermail/chicago-talk/2015-September/006583.html) you need to install OpenSSL first.

Comment: openssl is actually installed. Weird. 
`brew list` shows
`openssl` is installed. Not sure what the Makefile.PL is though