# How to install the packages under `virtual environment` on my Mac?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I follow the [tutorial](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/), I make the virtual environment, and I am under the `venv` in my Mac now:

```
(venv) HibMacBook:venv hib$
```

And now I want to install the `openssl-devel` and `zlib-devel`, I tried use homebrew

```
homebrew install openssl-devel   -y
homebrew install zlib-devel  -y
```

But failed, and I can not use wget because there is no those tools.

How can I install the packages under `virtual environment`?

---

**EDIT**

I tried use the pip to install in my venv, but failed too.

```
(venv) l$ pip install openssl-devel
Collecting openssl-devel
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openssl-devel (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for openssl-devel
```

---

**EDIT-2**

When I use brew to install openssl-devel, I will get bellow errors:

```
(venv) xxxx:venv ldl$ brew install openssl-devel
Updating Homebrew...
Error: No available formula with the name "openssl-devel" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: use `pip` it will install it to whatever environment you are in, in this case your venv. Btw. what exactly do you need from openssl and zlib? Is this a package requirement?

Comment: I want to install Python3.5

Comment: This post may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/46113935/7732200

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko See my EDIT-2.

Comment: as far I know, there is no separate package openssl-devel for mac, its functionality included in openssl

Comment: and this tutorial may be useful to get openssl http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/openssl/

Answer (score 0):

first, see if those packages are available:

- **pip**: `pip search <query>`
- **Homebrew**: `brew search <query>`

also, keep in mind the particular usage of each

- **pip**: pkg manager for Python
- **Homebrew**: pkg manager for Mac

meaning, pip should not be used to install OpenSSL; if you want an abstraction above OpenSSL, check out pyOpenSSL [https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api.html]